# How to use libspotify to play radio

Tags: spotify, playlist, internet-radio, libspotify

When I start radio of spotify,there are some general stations like classical,country etc.I want to get the playlists of these stations with libspotify,so I can play music as categorys in my own application.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality isn't available in libspotify at this time.

Comment: In my callback function logged_in,I implement three function 
link=sp_link_create_from_string("spotify:track:1NrJYpdAi7uosDRPmSYrsG");
sp_session_player_load(g_sess,sp_link_as_track(link));
sp_session_player_play(g_sess, 1);
but I got load failed:resource not loaded yet